# Adding 2 Event Handler in 1 Control

Tags: c#

im doing on a context-menu can be found on rightclick like in actual code-editor something like this:
[image]

and im already done with the cut,copy and paste by using this code:

```
private void rtb_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            {

                MenuItem[] menuItems = new MenuItem[] { 
                                        new MenuItem("Cut", new System.EventHandler(this.CutMenuItemClick)), 
                                        new MenuItem("Copy", new System.EventHandler(this.CopyMenuItemClick)),
                                        new MenuItem("Paste", new System.EventHandler(this.PasteMenuItemClick)), 


                ContextMenu rightcontext = new ContextMenu(menuItems);

                int xOffset = Cursor.Position.X - DtexteditoR.ActiveForm.Location.X;
                int yOffset = Cursor.Position.Y - DtexteditoR.ActiveForm.Location.Y;

                rightcontext.Show(DtexteditoR.ActiveForm, new Point(xOffset, yOffset));

            }
        }
private void CutMenuItemClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            rtb.Cut();
        }
        private void CopyMenuItemClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            rtb.Copy();
        }
        private void PasteMenuItemClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            rtb.Paste();
        }
```

**im using winforms with a dynamic control** (dont use designer) and my question was on how to make multiple event handler in a control (different handler) something like this:

```
new MenuItem("Copy", new System.EventHandler(this.CopyMenuItemClick) || new System.Windows.Forms.MeasureItemEventHandler(this.MeasureCopy)),

private void MeasureCopy(object obj,
                           MeasureItemEventArgs miea)
        {
            MenuItem mi = (MenuItem)obj;

            // Get standard menu font so that the text in this
            // menu rectangle doesn't look funny with a
            // different font
            Font menuFont = SystemInformation.MenuFont;

            StringFormat strfmt = new StringFormat();
            SizeF sizef =
                miea.Graphics.MeasureString(mi.Text, menuFont, 1000, strfmt);

            // Get image so size can be computed
            Bitmap bmMenuImage = new Bitmap(typeof(NewForm), "COPY.BMP");

            // Add image height and width  to the text height and width when 
            // drawn with selected font (got that from measurestring method)
            // to compute the total height and width needed for the rectangle
            miea.ItemWidth = (int)Math.Ceiling(sizef.Width) + bmMenuImage.Width;
            miea.ItemHeight = (int)Math.Ceiling(sizef.Height) + bmMenuImage.Height;
        }
```

for me to enable to add image beside "Copy" .

how to do this thing:

```
new MenuItem("Copy", new System.EventHandler(this.CopyMenuItemClick) || new System.Windows.Forms.MeasureItemEventHandler(this.MeasureCopy)),
```

the right way .thanks!

Comment: I don't know if I understand it correctly but if you are using multiple event handlers for one event (from one control) then which event handler would be fired? the first one or the second one? Let's say if I click copy in one time CopyMenuItemClick is fired but on another time it was MeasureCopy. But if you would say that after CopyMenuItemClick then that's the time that MeasureCopy is used then  I think that makes more sense. See this link here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/70cc4de1-cdda-4f1b-92a5-407443b2f591.

Answer (score 1):

I would just use

```
MenuItem item = new MenuItem("Copy");
item.Click += this.CopyMenuItemClick;
item.Click += this.MeasureCopy;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `MeasureItem` event cannot be set from the constructor, try:

```
MenuItem item = new MenuItem("Copy", new System.EventHandler(this.CopyMenuItemClick));
item.MeasureItem += this.MeasureCopy;
```